# Band ratio with Euler's number in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, multi-band, mathematics, band, band-ratio

I've band ratio with exponential equation and Euler's number

`band_ratio = (0,0039e)^(2,4952*(B2/B4))`

Can anyone write it in Google Earth Engine format?
Or just input the Euler's number?

Comment: Are you sure that your expression is right? I did a test with a Sentinel 2 product and the values were too low (about 1e-8).

Comment: yes that right. it's an equation from journal. they create new graph equation from in situ data and digital number of band ratio..  it think it's called exponential regretion.. so i just write the euler's number manually since i dont know how to get this constant from GEE...